# what is the difference DataView and DataRowView

Tags: c#, system.data

I would like to know the difference between DataView and DataRowView. I looked up on MSDN and it says the DataRowView is just a customized representation of DataView.

But can you also cast a DataView to DataRowView? Please explain

Many thanks

Comment: Could you point this reference with a link?

Comment: DataView is a view on a collection of rows in a table, DataRowView is a view on a collection of columns in a row.  You cannot cast a row to a column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `DataRowView` is a `DataRow` from a `DataView`.

Answer (score 5):

A [DataView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a subset of a DataTable, or a special "View" of it.

> Represents a databindable, customized view of a DataTable for sorting, filtering, searching, editing, and navigation. The DataView does not store data, but instead represents a connected view of its corresponding DataTable. Changes to the DataView’s data will affect the DataTable. Changes to the DataTable’s data will affect all DataViews associated with it.

A [DataRowView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a row in the DataView, so it's a special "View" of a DataRow.

> Represents a customized view of a DataRow.

The two are not the same thing.

The DataRowView object does have a Row property, which points it to the DataRow it represents.  Likewise, the DataView object has a Table property, which points it to the DataTable it represents.

Answer (score 2):

MSDN says that a [DataRowView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is:

> Represents a customized view of a DataRow.

So it is not referring to the DataView.

However the DataRowView is just a class used to represent a DataRow in the sort order applied to the DataView. In fact you could find between its properties the reference back to the DataRow